# nondecreasing f prove integrable with upper and lower sums

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

I have been given a question as such:

If $f$ is nondecreasing on $[0,1]$ use upper and lower sums to prove $f$ is Riemann Integrable.
So I know that using upper and lower sums to prove a riemann integral I have to show that the upper sum equals the lower sum and I know that

the upper sum = $\sum_{j=1}^{n} M_j(x_j-x_{j-1})$

the lower sum = $\sum_{j=1}^{n} m_j(x_j-x_{j-1})$

Where the x's are the size of the intervals and the big M is the upper height and little m is lower height. I'm just not so sure how I should go about using the fact f is non decreasing to prove the lower and upper sums equal each other.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is non decreasing you can give explicit expressions in terms of $f$ for $M_i$ and $m_i$.

Comment: Ok, so I'm pretty sure I can say $m_i \le f(x) \le M_i$ because $f$ is nondecreasing, and that satisfies one of the properties of the Riemann Integral. I can also probably say $m_i(x_i - x_{i-1}) \le f(x)$, and $M_i(x_i - x_{i-1}) \ge f(x)$, correct? Is this enough to prove the function is Riemann integrable? Is it even correct? I've just been introduced to these sums so I'm still trying to gain some intuition on the topic.

Comment: $m_i\le f(x)\le M_i$ holds wether $f$ is decreasing or not. Another hint: if $f$ decreases in $[x_{i-1},x_i}]$, what is the maximum value it can have? At which $x$ does it take that maximum value?

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is nondecreasing, then the lower sums would be strictly increasing and bounded above by the upper sums. Simply apply the monotone convergence theorem from there.